# How to fix my bash prompt with long lines?

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt

I have the following bash prompt:

```
YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
RESET='\e[0m'

export PS1="$GREEN[\W]$YELLOW \$(__git_ps1 \"(%s) \")$RESET\\$ "
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Which is what I want. However, when I enter a long line, it does not break the line at all but rather overwrites the current one from the beginning of the line. When this happens and I hit backspace, everything in that line will disappear. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to wrap the value of `$RESET`.

```
RESET='\[\e[0m\]'
```

Bash must know how long the prompt is in order for word-wrap to work correctly, and everything *not* between `\[` and `\]` is counted.

Comment: It's not about prompt length but the escape sequence parameters list. You could add several of them e.g. to make the text bold, inverted and underlined etc.

Comment: @Rajish: Okay, and why would that break line-wrapping?

Comment: @grawity The `\[` and `\]` escapes delimit non-printing characters sequence. Leaving them out probably breaks some terminal behaviour or internal bash parsing rules. http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Printing-a-Prompt

Comment: @Rajish: Which is exactly what my answer says. Leaving them out breaks the internal bash prompt-length-computation "rules".

Answer (score 3):

More portable using [`tput`](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Tput):

```
fgred="$(tput setaf 1)"
fggreen="$(tput setaf 2)"
fgyellow="$(tput setaf 3)"
fgblue="$(tput setaf 4)"
fgpurple="$(tput setaf 5)"
fgcyan="$(tput setaf 6)"
fgwhite="$(tput setaf 7)"

bgred="$(tput setab 1)"
bggreen="$(tput setab 2)"
bgyellow="$(tput setab 3)"
bgblue="$(tput setab 4)"
bgpurple="$(tput setab 5)"
bgcyan="$(tput setab 6)"
bgwhite="$(tput setab 7)"

bold="$(tput bold)"
underline="$(tput smul)"
reset="$(tput sgr0)"

export PS1="${fggreen}[\W]${fgyellow} \$(__git_ps1 \"(%s) \")${reset}\\$ "
```

Comment: Wow. I've never heard of tput before. Thanks!

Comment: tput is good, but eh, I've never seen a *not* VT220-compatible terminal [emulator] in active use these days. Also, noting lack of `\[` `\]`.

Comment: @grawity: the other advantage of tput is that you know what to search in the manual if you don't understand what the script does.